# Transforming vector into matrix-like object

Tags: r, vector, reshape

I have a trouble with transforming vector into matrix-like object. From the first sight, it must be very easy problem, but I didn't manage to solve it yet.

**Descriptinon of the problem:**

I have some long vector, which resembles the below mentioned one:

```
m <- c("100€", "25m²", "2 rooms", "12m²", "4 rooms", "500€", "3 rooms")
```

I wish to transfer it into the data.frame (or matrix) of the following structure:

```
  price surface    rooms
   100€    25m²  2 rooms 
     NA    12m²  4 rooms
   500€     NA   3 rooms
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may try something like this, calculate the column and row index respectively and then assign the vector to the matrix using the indices:

```
col <- ifelse(grepl("€", m), 1, ifelse(grepl("m²", m), 2, 3))

col
# [1] 1 2 3 2 3 1 3

row <- cumsum(c(T, diff(col) < 0))     # calculate the row index based on the column index, 
                                       # when you encounter a decrease of the column index, 
                                       # increase the row index by one
row
# [1] 1 1 1 2 2 3 3

mat <- matrix(nrow = max(row), ncol = max(col))
mat[cbind(row, col)] <- m

mat
#     [,1]   [,2]   [,3]     
#[1,] "100€" "25m²" "2 rooms"
#[2,] NA     "12m²" "4 rooms"
#[3,] "500€" NA     "3 rooms"
```

Comment: Very nice automatic detecting of where the `NA`'s should be included!

Comment: @ProcrastinatusMaximus Thanks!

Comment: Great! Perfect solution! Love it!

Comment: Just to add an alternative to nested `ifelse`s, something like `max.col(sapply(c("€", "m²", "rooms"), grepl, m), "first")` could be used.